# Using Backbone.js, I would like to display model data from database

Tags: backbone.js

I have defined a model within it I have default model schema. I have a respective collection and views defied for it.

I have the model data stored as documents in Couchdb.My question is,  How can I render these items in a browser.

I guess I am missing something small here with regard to linking the db and backbone.js. A little bit of direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display/visualize the data you need views. Backbone.js provides a very skinny views layer with no magic in built. So in almost all but the most simplest cases you would like to auxiliate your mvc architecture with some user interface widget framework like YUI to provide UI components like datagrid or visualization toolkits to provide graphs and charts. 
Of course you can stitch in plugins or create your own ui components in the view layer.

Backbone.js provides absolute freedom of choice to you to use whatever ui components you like in your views and unlike sproutcore/ cappuccino does not provide a hardwired ui framework.

So you would create view classes that perform the job of rendering the ui elements either by doing the hardwork themselves or by delegating them to some external library. In a typical scenario you will have nested views to provide a robust and responsive application interface. Eg. in a gridview you can have a master view for the whole table and views representing individual rows. If you are using sophisticated cell renderers then you can have the cell rendering logic in further nested views.